# Group by query behaviour in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

Table in mysql contains below records:

```
    +----------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+

    | PersonID | LastName | FirstName | Address | City  |

    +----------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+

    |        1 | Kumar    | Amit      | Sec-22  | Noida |

    |        2 | Kapoor   | X         | Sec-24  | Noida |

    |        3 | Kapoor   | Y         | Sec-22  | Delhi |

    |        4 | Kapoor   | Z         | Sec-25  | Delhi |

    |        5 | Kapoor   | W         | Sec-25  | Gzb   |

    +----------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+
```

When I run the below query:

```
    select City, FirstName from Persons group by City;
```

Below is the result shown:

```
+-------+-----------+
| City  | FirstName |
+-------+-----------+
| Delhi | Y         |
| Gzb   | W         |
| Noida | Amit      |
+-------+-----------+
```

I don't understand why all firstNames for each city are not shown in table, As there are 2 records present for Noida and Delhi each and 1 for Gzb

Please help me understanding this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Amitsh

Generally, Group By is used in conjunction with aggregate functions (to aggregate data).

Assuming FirstName is a "character" field, hence the Interpreter is by default grouping the column FirstName by the FIRST() value.

You would get expected output, if suppose, there is a salary column for each individual and you want to display the salaries earned in a city. (Just an example)

You may refer the following links to understand the application of Group By.

It would help us to help you if you let us know what is your expectation from this query.

Reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm

Answer (score 0):

Group by in `MYSQL` returns the first row entry and groups rest of the entries based on the column having group by filter.

In your case, Delhi has Y and Z, it groups into 1 row but would show Y since that is the first row. I am not sure about `MS-SQL`, I assume that works in the same way as group by works in `MYSQL`

Answer (score 0):

Group by shows the first entry you have.

Make this query:

```
select count(*) from Persons group by City;
```

You will have the count by group by. I think the query:

```
select City, FirstName from Persons order by City asc;
```

is more usefull for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `group by` and try selecting some other columns in the same query, mysql does not give guarantee of what value will be selected from all, it will randomly pick up one data.

In your case the query is

```
select City, FirstName from Persons group by City;
```

So it will select `City` and any of the `Firstname` for that city while you do `group by City`

More over the `group by` is more preferable for aggregate functions like sum, count etc.

You may however modify the query to get all the firstname as comma-separated string using `group_concat()`  function as

```
select 
City, 
group_concat(FirstName) as FirstNames 
from Persons group by City;
```